# Intercept method call on method that is tested OR get control over object created in method

Tags: java, mockito

I have currently this the issue that there is an object of Type `CoolObj` created within my method `doSomething()`.

This object goes through some processes and at the end I want to verify if everything is ok and then continue.

Now the problem is that I cannot control the behavior and **prevent** an exception to be thrown.

Either `hasErros()` should return `false` or I kind of mute the verify method. But I could not figure out how.

Any idea how to solve this issue please?

```
public class ExampleClass {

    public void doSomething(){
        CoolObj coolObj = new CoolObj();

        verify(coolObj);
    }

    private void verify(CoolObj coolObj) {
        if(coolObj.hasErrors()){
            throw new Exception(); //this is my issue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For something like this, you need to make the method `verify()` package private so it can be tested.  This allows dependency injection so you can inject a mocked `CoolObj` into the `verify()` method.  Or you need to use a test framework that lets you call private methods.  I think SuperMock does this, but you should check which is the best for you.

Comment: Can you change `coolObj` to be a parameter to `doSomething()` instead of creating a new instance?  If not, another approach is to create and inject a `CoolObjFactory` into `ExampleClass`, where `doSomething()` calls the factory.  The factory can be mocked to return a `coolObj` in whatever state is needed for the test.

Comment: The factory method is indeed a clever workaround - I would go for it when there is no better solution. Regarding the DI I don't see how this should work here since I have no way to tell doSomething to create a mock instead of a real object?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the problem that you have is related to the fact, that test doesn't control creation of `CoolObj` instances (that's because `ExampleClass` is not designed in testable way).

The best approach would be to change the design of `ExampleClass`, for example by delegating creating `CoolObj` instances to corresponding factory. Then mock instance created by factory and setup needed responses of `hasErrors` by `Mockito`.

However, if for some reason you are forced to leave the design of `ExampleClass` as is, then you can use `PowerMock` to [mock construction of new instances](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects).

For the code snippet provided in the question, following is an example of tests with and without exception thrown:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ExampleClass.class)
public class ExampleClassTest {

    private final ExampleClass exampleClass = new ExampleClass();

    @Test
    public void exceptionIsNotThrownIfCoolObjHasNoErrors() throws Exception {
        CoolObj coolObjMock = Mockito.mock(CoolObj.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(CoolObj.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(coolObjMock);
        Mockito.when(coolObjMock.hasErrors()).thenReturn(false);

        Assertions.assertThatCode(exampleClass::doSomething)
                .doesNotThrowAnyException();
    }

    @Test
    public void exceptionIsThrownIfCoolObjHasErrors() throws Exception {
        CoolObj coolObjMock = Mockito.mock(CoolObj.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(CoolObj.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(coolObjMock);
        Mockito.when(coolObjMock.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);

        Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(exampleClass::doSomething)
                .isInstanceOf(RuntimeException.class);
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. For more details, regarding code snippet in the answer [take a look here](https://github.com/zghurskyi/investigations/blob/master/investigation-powermock/src/test/java/org/example/ExampleClassTest.java).
2. Please, note that to work properly [PowerMock and Mockito should have compatible versions](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions).